# Beginner question before my real question

Tags: discussion, questions

Are There Females On This website? If so how do I ask them questions? I’m sorry I’m new to this site and I am new to Islam. I don’t have an Muslim females to talk to so I have been researching and trying to learn but to have someone answer certain questions I have would greatly help

Comment: you have no way to privately contatc sisters on this website. so one way is that you can ask that question in open (in public) but dont share your true identity (like change your name, instead of your real name).

Comment: what @HamzaIslam is true since this site is public site. however, asking a question (TO FIND TRUE IN ISLAM FOR the sake of ALLAH) is possible and will not be blamed of get sin. Just keep private your ID. :D

Comment: 'A'isha said: How good are the women of Ansar that their shyness does not prevent them from learning religion. [Hadith Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/3/72)

Answer (score 1):

There are women on this website. If you are interested in asking a question and getting an answer from a woman's point of view, you can specify that you want a woman's point of view in your question.

Comment: Are you implying that only a woman only answer when you say "woman's pov"? Way I see it asking for a (wo)man's pov should by closed as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to understand, if your question is really related to the subject of Islam then how can the sex of a user be even relevant to the answer. And if it is otherwise, seeking female advice/opinion, then I am afraid those questions cannot be catered on this site. Or if you could provide an example to establish its importance?

FWIW, answer(s) to your question should be of utmost importance and not the age, sex, race and color of the author. You could explicitly ask for answers to be backed-up with reliable references so that you can gain more confidence in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are many women here. If you need to ask to muslim women then it is good to learn much about it. In Islam, you can ask everything you need to know to save you and our life based on Allah wishes.

If the question is too sensitive to ask, you can ask their email (I would be pleased to answer if possible and to the best I could help) privately if you're sure you really trust them.

When muslim asks a question about Islam, but no one answers it even they know and has knowledge about it = they will get sin.
So, keep REALLY FREE to ask because you're muslim.